# How to use echo command to print out content of a text file?

Tags: unix

I am trying to figure out what is the usage of this command:

```
echo < a.txt
```

According to text book it should redirect a programs standards input. Now I am redirecting a.txt to echo but instead of printing the content of the file it is printing out one empty line!

Appreciate if anyone display this behaviour.

Comment: What command have you tried?

Comment: As I said I tried : echo < a.txt

Comment: @fedorqui  So what is the usage of: echo < a.txt

Comment: `echo` taking `stdin`? What kind of OS should it be to behave like that? it really shouldn't

Comment: There **no** usage for this command.

Comment: @keltar, can you explain why providing this functionality would be such a crime?

Comment: @AndrewS I suppuse the short answer is because it is non-standard. There's already a `cat` to do that. Extending `echo` with stdin on one system will just result "ok I can use echo as cat" situation, but then you go to another system and now you can't and you wonder why. It will also introduce a lot of questions like what should be its return value if stdin failed, and since it is non-standard, different implementations may have different ideas about that. I don't think anyone really wants that to happen.

Comment: @AndrewS but that's just part of it, another part is I don't really think it is possible. How would you distinguish `echo foo` to output "foo" but `echo `(empty variable, no value) to just wait for user input through stdin? That'll probably break like a half of existing scripts.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`echo` doesn't read stdin so in this case, the redirect is just meaningless.

`echo "Hello" | echo`

To print out a file just use the command below

`echo "$(<a.txt )"`

Comment: Here for future reference: in my case, `echo "$(<a.txt )"` works with a bash shell (`bash`), but not with a Bourne shell (`sh`) - meaning that if you want this `echo "$(<a.txt )"` to work, you might need to have the first line of your script as `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`. Otherwise, it might not work.

Comment: Cyber Security Perspective: In restricted shells, `echo "$(<flag.txt )"` command might be handy to read files if it is allowed to be execute. Disclaimer: The information provided in this post is for educational purposes only and does not constitute legal advice.

Answer (score 10):

In Unix, I believe all you have to do, assuming you have a file that isn't hefty is:
`cat <filename>`

No `echo` required.

Answer (score 3):

cat command will display the file with **CR or return**:

```
$ cat names.txt 
Homer
Marge
Bart
Lisa
Maggie
```

you could use echo command with cat as command substitution. However, it will replace CR or return (unix: \n) with spaces:

```
$ echo $(cat names.txt)
Homer Marge Bart Lisa Maggie
```

Could be an interesting feature if you want to pipe to further data processing though. E.g. replacing spaces with sed command.

Answer (score 2):

I using this way to print out content of a text file:

```
echo 'Testing' > test.txt
```

And i using the cat command to see the content of file.

```
cat test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

use below command to print the file content using echo,

```
echo `cat file.txt`
```

here you can also get benefit of all echo features, I most like the removing of trailing newline character, (to get exact same hash as that of buffer and not the file)

```
echo -n `cat file.txt` | sha256sum
```

Answer (score 0):

**The** `echo` **command** does not accept data from standard input (`STDIN`), but **only works on the arguments passed to it**.

So if we pass data to `echo` from standard input, e.g. with `<` or `|`, it will be ignored because `echo` only works with arguments.

**This can be changed by using** `echo` **together with the** `xargs` **command**, which is designed to call a command with arguments that are data from standard input.

For example:

```
xargs echo < file.txt
```

or

```
cat file.txt | xargs echo
```

Answer (score -6):

your can use

```
type test.txt
pause
```

Comment: On Windows yes, but not on Unix ??